# How to have unique ID for each row in normative tables?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, counters

I would like to find an easy way to create unique references for each normative row of a table. The reference have the form:

- A letter for the category
- The current table reference number
- An incremented value for each row

The following example works, but it is cumbersome. I have to create a new counter and mention the caption of the current table on each row. Instead I would like to have something like:

```
\begin{table}
\stdcategory{S}
\caption{Description \label{label}}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \stdref & Foo \\ 
    \stdref & Bar \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The example:

```
Figure \ref{specifications-directives} shows the hierarchy to be used with the identifiers. The plain arrow means “belongs
to” and the blank arrow means “refers to”. A deliverable is based on a task. Requirements and
specifications belong to a deliverable.
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \newcounter{tablecounter}
  \setcounter{tablecounter}{1}
  \caption{Specification Directives \label{specifications-directives}}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}\hline
    \textbf{ID}       & \textbf{Directive} \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & The requirements \textbf{shall} list “what” the system have to do \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Each requirement specification \textbf{shall} have a unique identifier \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Each unique identifier \textbf{shall} be considered once the final document is released \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & A document is released when it is formally approved by all involved parties \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Entries are numbered with a prefix following table \ref{directives} \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Only the verbal forms listed in table \ref{verbal-forms} \textbf{can} be used in requirements/specifications \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & A table \textbf{shall} contain only one prefix type entry \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & A table entry \textbf{shall} not exceed one line unless for sake of readability \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Requirements and specifications \textbf{shall} always be given using a table of entries \\ \hline
    S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter & Additional explanation \textbf{may} be added as standard text referring the entry number \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The row id appears to start with `2` instead of with `1`. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that works by defining a new column type -- called `x` below -- that takes a prefix label -- say, `S` -- as its argument and displays the normative number as `<prefix label><table number>-<row number>`.

The counter that keeps track of the row number -- named `directcntr` in the code below -- is reset automatically each time a table-related `\caption` directive is executed; hence, please place the `\caption` statement at the *top* of the table. If you want the prefix to be `S`, employ `x{S}`. And if you want the previx label to be `Y`, employ `x{Y}` in the list of column specs of the `tabularx` environment.

Directives may be cross-referenced by their fancy row numbers using the standard LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. The code below also provides some code needed to enable cross-referencing via the user macros, such as `\cref`, of the [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\counterwithin{table}{section} % optional
%% Define a new counter and bind it to the 'table' counter:
\newcounter{directcntr}[table] 

\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

%% Now define a new column type
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
     >{\renewcommand\thedirectcntr{#1\thetable-\arabic{directcntr}}%
       \refstepcounter{directcntr}\thedirectcntr} l }

%% Optional: Load cleveref package and inform it how to create 
%%           cross-referencing call-outs to directive-type items
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{directcntr}{directive}{directives}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault % optional
\sffamily % optional 

\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{table}{2}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\caption{Specification Directives\strut} 
\label{specifications-directives}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| x{S} | L |} % <-- note 'x{S}'
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{ID}} & \textbf{Directive} \\ 
\hline
 & The requirements \textbf{shall} list “what” the system have to do \\ \hline
 & Each requirement specification \textbf{shall} have a unique identifier \\ \hline
 \label{directive:unique}
 & Each unique identifier \textbf{shall} be considered once the final document is released \\ \hline
 & A document is released when it is formally approved by all involved parties \\ \hline
 \label{directive:prefix}
 & Entries are numbered with a prefix following table \ref{directives} \\ \hline
 & Only the verbal forms listed in table \ref{verbal-forms} \textbf{can} be used in requirements\slash specifications \\ \hline
 & A table \textbf{shall} contain only one prefix type entry \\ \hline
 \label{directive:not_exceed}
 & A table entry \textbf{shall} not exceed one line unless for sake of readability \\ \hline
 & Requirements and specifications \textbf{shall} always be given using a table of entries \\ \hline
 & Additional explanation \textbf{may} be added as standard text referring the entry number \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{directive:prefix,directive:not_exceed,directive:unique}.

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Yellow directives\strut} 
\label{tbl:next}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| x{Y} | L |} % <-- note 'x{Y}'
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{ID}} & \textbf{Directive} \\ 
\hline
 \label{directive:y1} & \dots \\ \hline
 \label{directive:y2} & \dots \\ \hline
 \label{directive:y3} & \dots \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{directive:y3,directive:y2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's very clever to use a new column type. The `\multicolumn{1}` is however not quite pretty.

Comment: @nowox - Not sure why you appear to dislike the use of `\multicolumn`. It's a perfectly general method for overriding column types, for 1 or more columns at a time. Is it the juxtaposition of "mutli" and "1" that's giving you pause? Well, blame the person who chose the macro's name for sub-par linguistic elegance and eloquence, but not the macro itself.

Comment: I always find the need for specific commands for total other usages a terrible move. Perhaps because I am a software developer and LaTeX has a considerable history. The name multicolumn is should split columns to acheiving "multiple columns". In your case, you wanna override some existing behaviour. I would prefer an `\override` command or perhaps overrides by default if the cell isn't empty.

Comment: @nowox the `\multicolumn` is just badly named, using it to override the preamble definition of a single column is very frequent, but if you feel better this way: `\newcommand\override{\multicolumn{1}}` and you can use `\override{l}{stuff}` instead of `\multicolumn{1}{l}{stuff}`.

Answer (score 4):

The following defines the special environment `directives`, that takes an optional argument (key=value with the keys `start` and `max`, with `start` specifying the first directives index and `max` defining the index with the biggest width), followed by two mandatory arguments (the single letter prefix and the `\caption`). The body of your environment should be the directives ending with `\\`. You can use `\label` inside the description of a directive to create references to this directive.

I also used `booktabs`-rules and dropped the vertical rules to get, imho, prettier results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\DeclareKeys[directives]
  {%
     max   .store = \directives@max
    ,start .store = \directives@start
  }
\SetKeys[directives]{max = 99, start = 1}
\newcounter{directivesrow}
\newdimen\directives@wd
\newcommand\directives@line
  {%
    \stepcounter{directivesrow}%
    \makebox[\directives@wd][l]{\thedirectivesrow}%
    \addtocounter{directivesrow}{-1}%
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{directives} {O{} m m}
  {%
    \SetKeys[directives]{#1}%
    \begin{table}
      \caption{#3}%
      \edef\thedirectivesrow{#2\thetable-\noexpand\arabic{directivesrow}}%
      \setcounter{directivesrow}{\directives@max}%
      \settowidth\directives@wd{\thedirectivesrow}%
      \setcounter{directivesrow}{\numexpr\directives@start-1\relax}%
      \begin{tabular}
        {
          @{\hskip\tabcolsep\directives@line\hskip2\tabcolsep}
          >{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{directivesrow}}
          p{\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-\directives@wd\relax}
        }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}
          {\makebox[\directives@wd][l]{ID}\hskip2\tabcolsep Directive}\\
        \midrule
  }
  {%
      \crcr
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    \end{table}
  }

% to get the counter formatting of your example
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{table}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{directives}[start=2]{S}{Specification Directives\label{directives}}
  \label{directive:shall}The requirements \textbf{shall} list “what” the system
    have to do \\
  Each requirement specification \textbf{shall} have a unique identifier \\
  Each unique identifier \textbf{shall} be considered once the final document is
    released \\
  A document is released when it is formally approved by all involved parties \\
  Entries are numbered with a prefix following table \ref{directives} \\
  Only the verbal forms listed in table \ref{verbal-forms} \textbf{can} be used
    in requirements/specifications \\
  A table \textbf{shall} contain only one prefix type entry \\
  A table entry \textbf{shall} not exceed one line unless for sake of
    readability \\
  Requirements and specifications \textbf{shall} always be given using a table
    of entries \\
  Additional explanation \textbf{may} be added as standard text referring the
    entry number \\
\end{directives}

\begin{directives}[max=9]{V}{Verbal Directives\label{verbal-forms}}
  random \\
  things
\end{directives}
You can even reference directive~\ref{directive:shall}!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcounter{tablecounter}
\setcounter{tablecounter}{1}
\newcommand{\mynum}{S\ref{specifications-directives}-\stepcounter{tablecounter}\thetablecounter}
\begin{document}
\figurename~\ref{specifications-directives} shows the hierarchy to be used with the identifiers.
The plain arrow means ``belongs to'' and the blank arrow means ``refers to''.
A deliverable is based on a task. Requirements and specifications belong to a deliverable.
\begin{table}
\caption{Specification Directives}
\label{specifications-directives}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,colspec={Q[l,m]X[l,m]},vlines,hlines,row{1}={font=\bfseries},row{1}={c},cell{2-Z}{1}={cmd=\mynum}}
ID & Directive                                                                                                    \\
   & The requirements \textbf{shall} list “what” the system have to do                                            \\
   & Each requirement specification \textbf{shall} have a unique identifier                                       \\
   & Each unique identifier \textbf{shall} be considered once the final document is released                      \\
   & A document is released when it is formally approved by all involved parties                                  \\
   & Entries are numbered with a prefix following table \ref{directives}                                          \\
   & Only the verbal forms listed in table \ref{verbal-forms} \textbf{can} be used in requirements/specifications \\
   & A table \textbf{shall} contain only one prefix type entry                                                    \\
   & A table entry \textbf{shall} not exceed one line unless for sake of readability                              \\
   & Requirements and specifications \textbf{shall} always be given using a table of entries                      \\
   & Additional explanation \textbf{may} be added as standard text referring the entry number                     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're stepping the counter twice for each row due to how `tabularray` works...

Comment: With your setup, one wouldhave to create a separate column type for each table that is supposed to display normative numbers. Can you relax this setup, so that the *current* table number, rather than the fixed number generated by `\ref{specifications-directives}`, is displayed?